# How to align Form element Center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

***[please see this picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PtWA.png)***

I'm trying to align 'form element' to center.

here is what I tried.

1.I used .form-inline {margin: 0 auto;}2. added  text-center in  form class="form-inline"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
<form class="form-inline">
<label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email"> </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="library/tether-master/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
< /html>
```

Could you please help me to find-out a solution of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
.form-inline {
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: table;
}
```

Comment: You saved me!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

if your are using twitter-bootstrap why you not center with bootstrap elements ?????  Offsetting columns

[image: getbootstrap].com/css/#grid-offsetting

here is the Bootstrap solution, and its responsiv!

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container jumbotron">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 column">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
          <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email"> </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```